# Next JS: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

Tags: next.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Error while importing image.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I am using nextjs

Comment: Does the file have a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? If so, is it allowed to?

Comment: no, I'm just importing an image and it's throwing errors

Comment: I guess, you'll have to add some code to get helpful answers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In next.config.js import next-images

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
```

and in module.exports use it like

```
module.exports = withImages({ ...//your content here })
```

Comment: what does the content exactly mean?

Comment: put path of images?

Comment: module.exports = withImages({ 
  target: '',
 webpack: function({...})
})

what ever configs you want to include for your project

Comment: what is 'next-images'? what is next.config.js? can be used in webpack.config.js?

Comment: ever got this working ? i dont know in module.exports = withImages({ ...//your content here }) what content @Prabhu is talking about

Answer (score 1):

for people having the problem @Prabhu answer is correct but you can use it like this with out giving content.
it worked for me with this error on .png image

Install: npm install next-images

in root dir => next.config.js

```
const withImages = require("next-images");
module.exports = withImages();
```